# Ruby on Rails 7 flickering effect while switching between light and dark theme

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2y3AglGKQ4&t=2s) to introduce the ability to switch between themes (light, dark or system default). It all works fine, however there is a bug in the form of a flickering effect.
For example, I am on LIGHT theme, I visit other subpages, all good, light theme is shown.
I switch to dark theme. It works, but when visiting other subpages, before the dark theme is applied, a light theme is shown for a second, creating some flicker.

Code changes given in the tutorial for this theme switching to work:

**application.html.erb** (clickable links):

```
<%= cookies[:theme] %>
<%= link_to 'Light', set_theme_path(theme: 'light') %>
<%= link_to 'Dark', set_theme_path(theme: 'dark') %>
<%= link_to 'System default', set_theme_path %>
```

**theme.scss**:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    .home {
      background:black;
      color: white;
    }

    .home.light {
        background: silver;
        color: black;
    }
  }


  @media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    .home {
        background: silver;
        color: black;

    }

    .home.dark {
        background:black;
        color: white;
    }
  }
```

**routes.rb**:

```
  get 'set_theme', to: 'theme#update'
```

**theme_controller.rb**:

```
class ThemeController < ApplicationController
    def update
        cookies[:theme] = params[:theme]
        redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path )
    end
end
```

Theme switching works, but I would like to remove this flickering effect. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing setting the theme directly in the HTML so it's there at the start of the load:

```html
<html class="<%= cookies[:theme] == 'dark' ? 'dark' : 'light' %>">
```

Apart from this I would recommend using StimulusJS to add the toggle and cookie setting via JS.